# How to avoid SwiftUI Initial View getting initialized multiple times when @State variables are initialized?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state

```
struct GroceryList: View {
  @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel:CoreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel() 
  @StateObject var userPreferences: UserPreferences = UserPreferences()
  @State private var selectedItemsInList: [GroceryItem] = []
  @State private var selection = Set<UUID>()//for check box
  @State private var activeTab:Int = 0 //for active tab
```

The above View gets initialized 3 times as and when the @State variables `selection` and `activeTab` gets initialized. I have a `init()` in `GroceryList: View`  like given below:

```
 init() 
{
   print("Grocery List View")
}
```

`Grocery List View` gets printed thrice.

Since I instantiate and initialize a CoreData View Model firstly, its `fetchItems()` in CoreDataViewModel init is also done thrice.

**How to avoid initialization happening multiple times?**

This is my first SwiftUI app in the development phase with self-learning.Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: We do not control how many times SwiftUI can create view, it is a struct (ie. value), so it can be many times... just don't have view's init heavy, preferably do nothing there except initializing properties..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreDataViewModel initializes 3 times most certainly because you have `@ObservedObject`, where you have to have `@StateObject`. Or you can inject this view model as a parameter, leaving `@ObservedObject`. Or you can use `@EnvironmentObject` in conjunction with `.environmentObject()` view modifier.

Also, if by "view initializes" 3 times, you mean its `onAppear` gets called multiple times - this means your view does not have stable identity. Check [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) talk to learn more, but briefly, you need to ensure that view has a stable structural identity, and/or explicit `.id()` identity.

Comment: How to give a View stable identity? Hope the https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/ helps. Any inputs also highly valuable.

Comment: This talk is probably the most useful one about SwiftUI. Clears a lot of things, especially about animation and poor performance.

Comment: Making CoreDataViewModel as @EnvironmentObject did it. Now VM does not get fetched 3 times. But view still inits thrice.

Comment: View's init effectively means it or its part rendering. For that to investigate you would need to carefully check what state changes. You can also employ a new tool `let _ = Self._printChanges()` available in iOS 15+.